# IIS ARR rules not working as expected in adding trailing slashes to my applications

Tags: regex, iis, web-applications, url-rewriting, arr

I have a pool of applications that I want to run under a ARR server that should serve as a router for all my applications.
I have defined a set of rules that should be applied in waterfall, but something is not working the proper way.

The first rule should handle the trailing slashes, the other rules should map my applications to resolve for my internal DNS server with rewrite URL, but the problem seems to happen during the first rule.

The default behaviour is that, if I try to launch my application with http://myapp will return 404 code, if I try to run it by adding the slash (http://www.myapp/ ) everything works fine. So basically my rule should check for URL patterns without the slash: if the resource is a directory it should add the slash at the end of the Url.

So the pattern to catch the url is the following regular expression:

```
.*[^/]$
```

This should catch url without / at the end and I successfully tested it.

For every url that matches the regexp, I should check if it's a directory, and in the case I should set the trailing slash, so:

```
{REQUEST_FILE} -> Is a directory
```

But this doesn't work. I also tried to add the following rule with no success:

```
{REQUEST_FILE} -> Is not a file
```

The rule to apply is the following:

**Redirect** to (**rewrite** leads to same behaviour, too):

```
{R:O}/
```

It seems not to add the / to my urls and I don't know how to check which steps fail to succeed. The next rules basically follow this pattern:

```
mywebapp/* redirect to  www.mydnsappaddress/{R:1}
```

EDIT: I add the web.config sample to show you the textual version of the rules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Trailing Slash" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*[^/]$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="app1" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="sites/doc/*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mypersonaldnsaddress/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="ASTCO portale NWS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="portale/*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mypersonaldnsaddress/{R:0/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you list the rules you are using, or at least a sample? They should appear as XML in your web.config file.

Comment: I added them in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask the obvious: does your example deliberately have `enabled` set to `false`?

I was able to make this work exactly as you desire: if the directory exists, add a slash at the end, if it doesn't, don't.

```
<rule name="Trailing Slash" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*[^/]$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/" />
</rule>
```